# Use @ngx-translate in standalone components in Angular 17

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-standalone-components

I use standalone components in Angular 17. When I used module architecture, I didn't have this problem. I added it to import in `AppModule` and it works good.

```
imports: [
 TranslateModule.forRoot(loader)
],
```

But if I add `TranslateModule.forRoot(loader)` in standalone components

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-main-work-space',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [
  // @ts-ignore
  TranslateModule.forRoot(loader)
 ],
 templateUrl: './main-work-space.component.html',
 styleUrl: './main-work-space.component.scss'
})
```

In result I have this mistake.

`✘ [ERROR] TS-992012: 'imports' contains a ModuleWithProviders value, likely the result of a 'Module.forRoot()'-style call. These calls are not used to configure components and are not valid in standalone component imports - consider importing them in the application bootstrap instead.`

I try add `@ts-ignore` but it doesn't help.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is your whole application standalone (you're [bootstrapping a standalone component](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#bootstrapping-an-application-using-a-standalone-component)) or is your application still module based (you have [a root `NgModule`](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping))?

Comment: You only want to use `SomeModule.forRoot()` once in your application (in the `imports` of a root `NgModule` when calling `.bootstrapModule()` in `main.ts`). Some packages have a `SomeModule.forChild()` method that can be used to import the package in a child `NgModule`.

Comment: If you're using a fully standalone application, you have access to `.bootstrapApplication()` and its [`ApplicationConfiguration`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationConfig) in which you can specify providers as if there were a root `NgModule`. There are cleaner ways if the package supports them, but calling `SomeModule.forRoot()` here is supported.

Comment: How can I add  ` TranslateModule.forRoot(loader)` to `ApplicationConfig`

Comment: You use [`.importProvidersFrom()`](https://angular.io/api/core/importProvidersFrom) like so: `.bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, { providers: [ importProvidersFrom(TranslateModule.forRoot(loader)) ] });`.

Comment: I did it but have the mistake in html in `/main-work-space.component.html`.  `translate` pipe is red and it proposes add `TranslateModule` to import in `MainWorkSpaceComponent`

Comment: You can just `imports: [TranslateModule]` in your component. There's no need to call `.forRoot()` there. This is the same thing you would do if importing into an `AppModule` (where you call `.forRoot()`) and a `SharedModule` (where you don't call `.forRoot()`).

Comment: In result I have this `main.ts:5 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_TranslateService -> _TranslateService -> _TranslateService]:`

Comment: I'm not sure what the transitive dependencies here are. That looks like there should be something else in the call to `.forRoot()` when bootstrapping the application. If `TranslateModule.forRoot()` doesn't return a provider for `TranslateService`, you might have to add one on your own: `providers: [TranslateModule.forRoot(loader), { provide: TranslateService, useFactory/useClass/useExisting: ... }]`. That's falling into configuration of `@ngx-translate`, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you missed the `importProvidersFrom` wrapper for `translation module`, please find below working example along with extra sample code, to help you resolve your problem!

```
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import 'zone.js';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule, TranslateModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>
      <label>
        {{ 'HOME.SELECT' | translate }}
        <select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{ lang }}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient],
        },
      })
    ),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-axafwc?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts)

[Stackblitz for reference not by me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxe78f?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: thank you, this has been giving me such a headache