# Injection error (NG0203) using ngx-translate pipe in angular 17 standalone component

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular17

We want to use ngx-tanslate in our angular-17 project, where we have no modules and only standalone components.

We get the following error:

```
 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:985:15)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:998:42)
at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:12042:16)
at TranslatePipe_Factory (ngx-translate-core.mjs:1050:40)
at Module.ɵɵpipe (core.mjs:28466:30)
at FooterComponent_Template (footer.component.html:21:8)
```

The error is thrown when the `translate`-pipe is called in the component template. The component definition looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  imports: [MatButtonModule, TranslateModule],
  standalone: true
})
```

The main.ts look like this:

```
export function createTranslateLoader(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient);
}
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    ...
    ),
    importProvidersFrom(
      BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
      ...,
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      })
    ),
  ]
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Who to fix it?

relates to: [Use @ngx-translate in standalone components in Angular 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77760502/use-ngx-translate-in-standalone-components-in-angular-17)

Comment: could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated,here is one Im using to check [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-axafwc-vp6clg?file=src%2Ffooter%2Ffooter.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ffooter%2Ffooter.component.html)

Comment: Could you also please provide the createTranslateLoader factory function?

Comment: @SirOneOfMany it is already there

Comment: Could you please include the template for `FooterComponent`? Are you using `@defer` blocks or similar? Here is a StackBlitz with a working Ngx Translate setup using only standalone components for reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sqtdq8?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i installed ngx-tanslate with `npm install @ngx-translate/core --save` as described in the [ngx-translate tutorial](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core?tab=readme-ov-file#installation), but the `--save` seems to have caused this error.

I solved the issue by adding `@ngx-translate/core` and `../http-loader` manually to the package.json dependencies.